# Safety Issues in Server Room

Tags: wifi

We work in a room with a large number of servers and are worried about the noise. It is finally well air conditioned and has two windows and we have nice desks etc... We are asking them to maybe put up at least a partition. One person is also worried about other hazards of being close to the electronics and the wireless signal. Is that a real concern?

Comment: IMHO this is off-topic.  The concern about wireless are silly.  See the OSHA guidelines for noise. http://www.osha.gov/SLTC/noisehearingconservation/

Comment: Provide the wifi-concerned employee a company-issued tin foil hat.  Is it a real concern?  [No](http://arstechnica.com/old/content/2007/07/new-study-suggests-that-cell-phone-sensitives-dont-exist.ars).

Answer (score 3):

In the USA there are OSHA standards with regards to ambient noise. If the ambient noise exceeds a certain threshold you are required to wear ear protection. I am sure that any EU countries have even **stricter** standards.

Even if it's not immediately "ear-piercing," prolonged exposure to elevated noise levels can damage your hearing.

http://www.osha.gov/SLTC/noisehearingconservation/

Answer (score -2):

noise is real concern, it greatly decrease workload posible and also can result other issues.

wireless signal in 0.5m is harmless, ur gsm device give more power in ur shorts;)
same with electronic in metal cases.